# Error in Google play to BigQuery transfer job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-play

I am getting this following error in my data transfer job which transfer data from Google play into BigQuery dataset daily.

Seems like sometimes it fails sometimes it succeeds .Check the screenshots.

Error code 5 : No files found for any reports. Please make sure you selected the correct Google Cloud Storage bucket and Google Play reports exist.

[image]

Comment: Does it always fail in the first run?

Comment: Yes , it always fail for the first run of the day.

Comment: If you postpone your first schedule a little bit, do the first run still results in an error? I interpret this error as "there are no Google Play files in this bucket at the moment"

Comment: Currently my schedule time is 4:15 UTC daily, by what value should i postpone it to? any definite value or just a random value?

Comment: Can be to 4:30 for example. The point is that if the schedule fails everyday in the same time is there any possibility that the files are not really there in that time?

Comment: Could be possible. Let me just try out this approach and see if it works. 
Thanks @rmesteves

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: I changed the time from 4:15 UTC to 16:15 UTC . and from the last 3 days that error didn't popped up again. I guess it does solved the problem .  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was discussed in the comments, the given error message `No files found for any reports` means that the reports doesn't exist in the when the transfer is run.

Postponing the schedule showed to be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Postponing the schedule time of job from 4:15 UTC to 16:15 UTC solved this issue.